# VB.net NUnit (2.5) Windows forms Testing - Is this possible

Tags: vb.net, winforms, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I am retrofitting unit testing into a fairly complex system designed and written by other developers in VB.net. I am *trying* to develop unit tests for the GUI forms using NUnit and the NUnit Forms extension. (I've been looking at c# examples that are fairly easy to port over if you have a solution but don't know VB syntax as long as it uses NUnit classes)

I will try and explain what I am doing but first a brief description of the program. It basically monitors server activity. You need to connect to a server via a modal form with IP and Port fields(amongst others). Once you have connected to a server other parts of the program unlock and become usable (such as configuration of the server).

Desired process: Load program > click connect button > modal connect form loads > enter details > click OK to connect > main form updates to logged-in state > other functionality

The problem is that I cannot test the functionality of the connect form and then the logged-in functionality of the program. I can test that it *loads* the modal connect form correctly; enters the details and clicks OK (all fine so-far) but it does not appear to logically progress the program. The modal form just closes again seemingly without running the connect code from the program back-end and I’m back at the main menu not logged in to anything.

I have a feeling that I’ve either missed something really obvious or that it’s simply not doable in NUnit. I have trawled the internet in search of anything similar but the closest was another SO thread that was really generic. Without being able to actually test the logged-in version of the program, I'm at a major hurdle.
Another issue is handling message boxes that don’t have unique identifiers (e.g. “are you sure you want to exit?”); these also seem to be a major pain in the arse with NUnit

(If it makes any difference, I’m running the tests as a stand-alone project using a reference to the executable file of the built project, not the actual source)

Can post some of my testing code if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about NUnit forms, but using the [White library](http://white.codeplex.com/) (which also works with NUnit), you're able to test the application by running the exe and mimicking user actions. The application runs normally so all application logic is performed.

Here's some example code for launching an app with White:

```
Dim app = White.Core.Application.Launch("MyApp.exe")
```

Accessing a form from your app:

```
Dim mainForm = app.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("MainForm"), 
                             InitializeOption.NoCache)
```

Performing an action such as clicking a menu item:

```
mainForm.MenuBar.MenuItem("Edit", "Jobs...").Click()
```

Getting a control and validating its state:

```
Dim someTextBox = mainForm.Get(Of TextBox)(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("txtValue"))
Assert.IsTrue(someTextBox.Text = "12345")
```

I'm not sure if NUnit Forms has similar capabilities, but if not, maybe you should look into White. I ran into some issues setting it up so make sure to read the documentation carefully (not very exhaustive unfortunately) before setting it up.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best approach to make GUI classes feasible for unit tests is to apply the [Model-View-Presenter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) and factor almost every program logic out of the form (=View) class to a separate Presenter class. Then you can unit test the Presenter class without the need for tools like "NUnit Forms".

Read [Michael Feathers' article "The Humble Dialog Box"](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/TheHumbleDialogBox.pdf) for an example in C++, you can easily apply that to Winforms, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. It was an interesting article and very useful, unfortunately It's not for me to say that the whole system needs to be recoded (I'm only a junior dev). All I want is to get this friggin' unit testing out of the way.

Comment: Splitting up a dialog class into 2 is far from "recoding the whole system" (ok, when you have a dialog with >20000 lines of code it may be). Think about how much time you will need to do this for your dialog, and how much time you invest to fight with this volatile, badly working "unit testing through GUI" approach.

Comment: @DocBrown: UI testing does not need to be volatile and badly working (good coding principles like code reuse should also apply to UI testing). Also it's pretty much your only choice when working with legacy apps, you want to have some form of tests before refactoring the code and taking the risk to break something.

Comment: @Meta-Knight: I made my experiences with some different GUI robot tools, including WinRunner from Mercury (today HP), which may be one of the best existing tools in this area. The experience was almost always, well, lets say "disillusioning". On the other hand, separating layout from logic and testing only the logic has proven to be a very effective way of testing.

Comment: @DocBrown: Correct me if I'm wrong, but tools like WinRunner use a custom scripting language which can't easily be coded into reusable functions. With tools like NUnitForms and White, UI tests are .NET code, inside your VS solution, which makes reuse easier. But I totally agree that it's a good practice to separate layout from logic, and that most tests should be unit tests focusing on logic ;-)

Comment: @Meta-Knight QTP (Quick Test Pro) is a UI testing tool and it is just like WinRunner that they use scripts.  However, you can create a methods that are completely reusable.  We have a massive library of code that we reuse all the time to UI test our legacy WinForms apps.  It can be a pain but quite possible.